# Displaying Multi column Listview in a dialog box

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to load a multi column listview in a dialog box. The list data is being fetched through an external webservice and stored in a map then Arralylist mlist. The list gets populated with data. I'm trying to show this data in a multicolumn listview which is embedded in a dialog box. I am trying to do this with the help of the below code

```
Dialog dialog1;
                     new fetchData().execute("1");

                    View vls;
                    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(context, mlist,
                            R.layout.custom,
                            new String[] { "Col1", "Col2","Col3" }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.C1, R.id.C2, R.id.C3 });
                    vls= MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom,
                             null);
                     dialog1 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                     dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                     ListView list =(ListView)vls.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
                        list.setAdapter(sa);
                         dialog1.setContentView(vls);


                     dialog1.show();
```

Here's the custom.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the listview.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/C1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C1" />    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/C2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:gravity="center"      
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:text="C2" />   
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/C3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:gravity="center"      
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:text="C3" />   
</LinearLayout>
```

The code runs without any errors but it doesn't show any data in the dialog box. Please help!

Comment: mList is filled when you call the execute method ?

Comment: yes..everything works fine except the dialog box

Comment: do this, try printing the size of mList before setting into the adapter :).. m sure it doesnt contain any items when you set it into the adapter

Comment: the list has the data. I've tested it!

Comment: when does it get data ? after execute() gets called ??